# Dynamic buffer or Dynamic Near

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]I am using ArcGIS 10.6 ArcMap License.

I am looking for a way to calculate the distance between polygons and the centerline of the street network. The aim to use this vale as the buffer value to identify the polygons that face the street (line shape).
For instance I tried the near feature, then taking near distance + tolerance as the buffer value. But still some polygons are not covered by the buffer and others totally covered depending on street width. When I increase the buffer value, that cause problem for the next step modeling. How Can I add the value to the buffer_value dynamically as the function of street width? Or to increase the buffer_value up to the limit that intersect with the near features polygon? I tried iterate but didn’t gave desired result.

Comment: I don't think buffer is a way to go. What is definition of the house facing the street?

Comment: @FelixIP there polygons that are not at the near distance or not facing the street (line shape). For example the polygons at the bottom right corner are not covered by the buffer.

Comment: Your definition reminds dreadful circular reference in Excel formula, neither is working. Perhaps you mean: house not facing the street if there's at least another one in between the house and nearest street or distance greater threshold.

Comment: dear Felix no I don't mean the polygon in the center of plots. I mean, the polygons at outer border of plots, which are at different distance from the street center line, i.e. with different threshold values. The formula that I use to calculate buffer-value from each street centerline , is not covering all the polygons near or adjacent to the street. I also tried iterate but  didn't get the desired result.